# Prove that $P$ is a lattice (details inside)

Tags: combinatorics, proof-verification, order-theory

Can someone please verify my proof or offer suggestions for improvement? There may be answers to the same questions elsewhere, but I need help with my proof in particular.

> Show that if $P$ is a finite poset such that
>
> (1) Every $x, y$ has a greatest lower bound
>
> (2) $P$ has a unique maximal element $\hat 1$
>
> then $P$ is a lattice.

We need to prove that every $x, y$ in $P$ has a least upper bound. Suppose, for the sake of contradiction, that there exists an $x, y \in P$ that does not have a least upper bound. There are two possible cases:

(1) $x, y$ has no upper bound: In this case, $x$ and $y$ are both maximal elements (note that it must be the case that $x \neq y$, or else $x$ would be a least upper bound for $x, y$.) This contradicts the fact that there exists a unique maximal element.

(2) $x, y$ has an upper bound $z_1$, but no least upper bound: In this case, the set of all upper bounds of $x, y$ is infinite, contradicting the fact that $P$ is a finite poset; if we are given an upper bound $z_i$, we can find a smaller upper bound $z_{i+1}$ such that $z_{i+1} \neq x, y$.

Therefore, it must be the case that every $x, y \in P$ has a least upper bound. Hence, $P$ must be a lattice.

Comment: Perhaps you could say a bit more why the set $\{x,y\}$ not having an upper bound implies both $x$ and $y$ are maximal (use finiteness).  It is also worth noting that the hypothesis that $P$ be finite is necessary.

Comment: @Hayden I don't understand. If $\{x, y\}$ does not have an upper bound, shouldn't it be the case that $x$ and $y$ are maximal, regardless of whether $P$ is finite?

Comment: No, for each of $x$ and $y$ can have their own individual upper bounds, but no common ones.  An example that satisfies all of the conditions you give except for the finiteness is the poset in which you have two copies of $\mathbb{N}$ (with their usual order) attached together at $0$ and then off to the side another random point $\hat{1}$ that is greater than the common zero and incomparable to everything else...

Comment: ...Then the two copies of $1$ that show up in $\mathbb{N}$ have no common upper bound, but there are least upper bounds (basically zero unless the two elements are in the same chain) and $\hat{1}$ is the unique maximal element.

Comment: @Hayden Ahhhhhh. Now I get it.